# AngularJS Nested Directives

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a nested directive structure in Angular like

```
<aa>
    <bb>
        <cc></cc>
    </bb>
    <bb>
        <cc></cc>
    </bb>
</aa>
```

Each directive would print its content, so *aa* tags will print "A", *bb* tags will print "B" and *cc* tags will print "C".
The problem is that the outer directive overwrites the inner ones so only the first directive is processed.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/x3420fg1/). What am I missing?

Comment: Why? Should `cc` specialize `bb`?

Comment: ng-controller's. Have them talk together through services that return a JSON object, if you need them to

Comment: @LutzHorn Consider aa tags like Continents, bb tags like states and cc tags like cities, this  will give you an example..

Comment: @J-Dizzle I don't want to use controllers for this, so that who writes HTML doesn't have to care about controllers and viceversa

Comment: @LucaDeNardi Could you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27542252/edit) and add an example that gives us an idea of what you want to do?

Comment: @LutzHorn Check the fiddle. I want to print A inside aa tags, B inside bb tags and C inside cc tags (With directives only).

Comment: My final suggestion would be use angular and write an attribute directive (a.k.a. i.e. <bb> </bb>) and you would just configure it in the directive which is more or less just plain JS. you tagged angularjs and not html??

Comment: @J-Dizzle I only tagged Angular because those are Angular-oriented tags. Check the marked answer, I only missed an attribute in the directive to make it work. That is what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `ng-transclude` from the templates

See http://jsfiddle.net/x3420fg1/1/

Comment: Thank you, I just found out it by myself before you answered :) This is the solution anyways!